# Swift: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: swift

After build I get this error :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/mohammad/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Project/iOS/iOS-p/Pods/Quickblox-WebRTC/QuickbloxWebRTC.framework/QuickbloxWebRTC, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/mohammad/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Project/iOS/iOS-p/Pods/Quickblox-WebRTC/QuickbloxWebRTC.framework/QuickbloxWebRTC (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCRemoteVideoView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerCall.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerChat.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCBaseSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerCall.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCCameraCapture", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerCall.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerChat.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCVideoFormat", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerCall.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerChat.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerCall.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerChat.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCConfig", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerCall.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerChat.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCAudioSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerCall.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerChat.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_QBRTCClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerCall.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewControllerChat.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I updated pod, clean, remove arm and ,,, but this error not removed

My code was worked fine

After `pod update` I get this error

How I can fix it ?

Comment: try [clean project, delete derived data, restart xcode]

Comment: @SPatel i try it. not wok

Comment: Please mentation in question, what you try.